# How to get image URL out of NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray

So I have an NSDictionary with 4 objects in it.  Each of these objects then has 2 properties, `name` and `date`

I can list out all the data by logging it.

Comment: What is the component type in that array? NSDictionary?

Comment: After extracting the URL, you'll also be needing to download the image file from that URL.

Comment: have you check your json is proper or not through    http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an NSArray which contains several dictionaries. Firstly,get one dictionary out of the array like this,

```
NSDictionary *myDict=[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

assuming u have this array under the name myArray. You will get the first dictionary from the array which contains medium,thumbnails,title and another key called url. thumbnails is an array which holds a dict wid a key called url. Now if u want to fetch the outside url key tat is in the myArray just do like this,

```
NSString *myURL=[myDict valueForKey:@"url"];
```

This should fetch the url value..Hope this helps.... Happy coding...

```
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData;
```

Now you have ur image. Just create an imageView and set this image to it. To add it to a table, use contentView property like this,

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:myImageView];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  How can I actually load the cell's image from the Url though?

Comment: You mean u want add tat image from the url to a tableview's cell ?

Comment: Thanks.  I get a crash at `NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];` that says `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d5f640'`

Comment: oops...sorry try this...first b4 doing iniWIthContentsOfURL for NSData... NSURL *myURL2=[NSURL urlWithString:myURL];

Comment: Hmm same problem.  I'm putting my code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I know why.  `myURL` NSLog to this: `2011-09-12 23:19:42.966 PulseChallenge[7781:707] myURL: (
        (
        "http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/screen-shot-2011-09-12-at-5-22-46-pm.png?w=150",
        "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d442840d878a0d027a177e8e2d66c7ae?s=96&d=identicon&r=G",
        "http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/screen-shot-2011-09-12-at-4-44-12-pm.png",
        "http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/screen-shot-2011-09-12-at-4-51-53-pm.png",
    )
)`

Comment: you are doing the conversion of string to url in initWithcontentsOfURl itself...so sorry need of the previous line of code...n btw just put an NSLog of the string or the URL after u obtain it and post it here....

Comment: Ok I NSLog myURL and posted output in question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3391/discussion-between-jon-and-booleanboy)